# Подключить локально COM объект

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, com

Подключаю COM `Microsoft.Interop.Excel`через `AddReference`, выбирая из списка. Затем пишу метод. Использую его. Все ОК. Теперь запускаю на машине, где не установлен пакет `Microfoft Office`. Приложение вылетает на потоке с методом. Делаю вывод, что из-за того, что нет пакета установленного. Скачиваю библиотеку с Интернета `Microsoft.Interop.Excel.dll` и кладу ее в корневую папку проекта (Release). Удаляю прежнюю ссылку на библиотеку и теперь подключаю её локально (через другие - обзор), т.е. не выбираю из списка. Компилирую. Запускаю на машине, где нет офиса. Приложение теперь бросает ошибку:

> Сбой при получении производства объектов класса СОМ для компонента CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} в результате следующей ошибки: 80040154.

Что делаю не так? И как можно профиксить? Можно ли вообще, чтобы приложение, содержащее метод, вызывающий работу с Excel, корректно работало на машинах, где пакета Офиса нет? (а вот так вот через локальное подключение библиотеки)
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
C# WinForms (.NET 3.5), OC Win10

Comment: Interop.Excel - это обертка, т.е. через нее идет обращение к COM-объектам которые образуют Excel, и если их нет или они не зарегистрированы, то работать не будет.

Comment: @Stack спасибо за разъяснение.  Можно ли вообще, чтобы приложение, содержащее метод, вызывающий работу с Excel, корректно работало на машинах, где Office не установлен?

Comment: если Excel не установлен, то нет. Если вам надо создавать или что-то менять в excel- или -word- файлах, то для этого есть OpenXML SDK

Comment: Ещё можно использовать ADO

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка возникает потому как Интерпоп работает напрямую с екселем. Без установленного екселя взаимодействие невозможно.

Для того что бы работать на машинах без екселя нужно использовать внешние библиотеки, например с помощью OpenXML, ClosedXML  или других либ.

Не уверен, но вероятно что реализация взаимодействия через OleDb так же даст результат возможной работы без екселя. Но сдесь гарантий не даю.

---

Обновление по вопросу вот сдесь:
[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134)